# Android app uses static method to transfer and plot data

Tags: android, multithreading, static, thread-safety

I've been asking questions regarding my Android project that continually plots Bluetooth data in real-time.

Basically what I've already done is create a first version of my app by cobbling together some open source code [Blueterm](http://pymasde.es/blueterm/) and [OrientationSensorExample](http://androidplot.com/wiki/OrientationSensorExample)

It's been suggested that I add a thread, a handler, a Service, or use Async Task, or AIDL, etc. But I don't know how to use any of these and would appreciate an explanation.

Here's a description of the Blueterm open source code I started with (see link above). Blueterm is basically a terminal emulator program that communicates over Bluetooth. It consists of several activities with Blueterm being the most important. It discovers, pairs, and connects with a remote Bluetooth device that supports SPP/RfComm. When connected I can use Blueterm to configure the remote device by sending it commands to turn on sampling, change the number of channels to sample (to one channel), change to format of the incoming data (I like comma separated data), etc

Here's a description of the OrientationSensorExample open source code I started with (see link above). It's basically an example application of the AnroidPlot library. The OrientationSensor activity implements SensorEventListener. This includes overriding onSenorChanged() which is called whenever new orientation sensor data is taken, and it redraws the graph.

Having cobbled together these two open source projects (Blueterm and OrientationSensorExample) into one application (Blueterm) here's a description of how the overall application (Blueterm) works. When I start Blueterm the whole screen emulates a nice blue terminal. From the Options Menu I discover, pair with, connect to, and configure a remote bluetooth device as described above. Once I have configured the remote device, I go again to the Options Menu and select "Plot data" which launches the Plot activity. The terminal emulator goes away, and a nice scrolling real-time plot from the Plot activity shows up.

As far as I can tell there is a background thread that calls an update() method as follows:

```
/**
 * Look for new input from the ptty, send it to the terminal emulator.
 */
private void update() {
    int bytesAvailable = mByteQueue.getBytesAvailable();
    int bytesToRead = Math.min(bytesAvailable, mReceiveBuffer.length);
    try {
        int bytesRead = mByteQueue.read(mReceiveBuffer, 0, bytesToRead);
        append(mReceiveBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

        //VTR use existing handler that calls update() to get data into plotting activity
        Plot.plotData(mReceiveBuffer, 0, bytesRead);

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        //VTR OMG their swallowing this exception
    }
}
```

In the update() method I found it convenient to call my Plot.plotData() method and pass it the same date that is passed to the append() method to plot the data. NOTE: This only works if plotData() is a static method. No one has been able to explain why.

Anyway plotData() is a static method and here's how it and it's helper methods look now:

```
private static StringBuffer strData = new StringBuffer("");
public static void plotData(byte[] buffer, int base, int length) {

    Log.i("Entering: ", "plotData()");

    /*
    byte[] buffer = (byte[]) msg.obj;
    int base = msg.arg1;
    int length = msg.arg2;
    */

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        byte b = buffer[base + i];
        try {
            if (true) {
                char printableB = (char) b;
                if (b < 32 || b > 126) {
                    printableB = ' ';
                }
                Log.w("Log_plotData", "'" + Character.toString(printableB)
                        + "' (" + Integer.toString(b) + ")");

                strData.append(Character.toString(printableB));
                if (b == 10)
                {
                    Log.i("End of line: ", "processBlueData()");
                    Log.i("strData", strData.toString());
                    splitData(strData);
                    strData = new StringBuffer("");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Log_plotData_exception", "Exception while processing character "
                    + Integer.toString(i) + " code "
                    + Integer.toString(b), e);
        }
    }

    Log.i("Leaving: ", "plotData()");
}

private static void splitData(StringBuffer strBuf) {
    String strDash = strBuf.toString().trim();
    String[] strDashSplit = strDash.split("-");
    for (int ndx = 0; ndx < strDashSplit.length; ndx++)
    {
        if (strDashSplit[ndx].length() > 0)
            Log.i("strDashSplit", ndx + ":" + strDashSplit[ndx]);
        String strComma = strDashSplit[ndx].trim();
        String[] strCommaSplit = strComma.split(",");
        for (int mdx = 0; mdx < strCommaSplit.length; mdx++)
        {
            if (strCommaSplit[mdx].length() > 0)
                Log.i("strCommaSplit", mdx + ":" + strCommaSplit[mdx]);
            if (mdx == 1)
            {
                int raw = Integer.parseInt(strCommaSplit[1],16);
                Log.i("raw", Integer.toString(raw));
                float rawFloat = raw;
                Log.i("rawFloat", Float.toString(rawFloat));
                float ratio = (float) (rawFloat/65535.0);
                Log.i("ratio", Float.toString(ratio));
                float voltage = (float) (5.0*ratio);
                Log.i("voltage", Float.toString(voltage));
                nowPlotData(voltage);
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void nowPlotData(float data) {

    // get rid the oldest sample in history:
    if (plotHistory.size() > HISTORY_SIZE) {
        plotHistory.removeFirst();
    }

    // add the latest history sample:
    plotHistory.addLast(data);

    // update the plot with the updated history Lists:
    plotHistorySeries.setModel(plotHistory, SimpleXYSeries.ArrayFormat.Y_VALS_ONLY);

    //VTR null pointer exception?
    if (plotHistoryPlot == null)
        Log.i("aprHistoryPlot", "null pointer exception");

    // redraw the Plots:
    plotHistoryPlot.redraw();
}
```

If it is strongly recommended that plotData() not be a static method and that I should do something else please explain here and how. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be a question much better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), rather than here. Perhaps you can reformulate to post it there, or trim it a lot to repost it here.

Furthermore, to answer: "It's been suggested that I add a thread, a handler, a Service, or use Async Task, or AIDL, etc. But I don't know how to use any of these and would appreciate an explanation.", the best advise would be to link you to a book about android, such as: http://commonsware.com/Android/ . Chapters 35 and 36 deal with services, while chapter 20 is about threads. You will never get an answer as complete as those chapters here.

Comment: thanks for the links! I'll check out Code Review and the CommonsWare book.

Comment: Ha! The chapters are not numbered in the table of contents! LOL

Comment: Chapter 20 "Dealing with Threads" page 255, Chapter 35 "Services: Theory" page 503, Chapter 36 "Basic Service Patterns", page 513. Of course one can search for the chapter titles. I think I finally got it right this time.